# Add new role to existing Azure service deployment

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

I have an Azure service which currently has a Web Role within it that has been deployed. I now have a need to add a Worker Role to the project to handle some maintenance, but I'm unable to upgrade the service deployment. When I attempt to deploy the new version of the service which includes both the Web Role and the Worker Role, I receive the following error.

> The number of roles specified by the service model differs between the service upgrade package and the currently deployed service. An upgrade is not supported in this case.

Is there a way to get the new version of my service deployed?

Answer (score 5):

This error message means you can't do an in-place automated upgrade (because azure doesn't know how to do an in-place upgrade between packages with different roles)

You can instead:

- deploy the new package to staging
- switch staging-production
- delete the old deployment which is now staging

Comment: This will work if the external endpoints do not change.  However, if the endpoints change, you cannot VIP swap and will need to delete/redeploy (or use DNS to make it look seamleass).

Comment: If you are in the situation that dunnry is talking about, then the best way to do things is a variation on this method and delete the currently running process in production before doing the VIP swap.  It's not as seamless as an in place upgrade, but it is quicker than deleting and deploying again.